# can ngx-restangular and @ngx-translate/core work together?

Tags: angular, restangular, ngx-translate

I'm trying to use both ngx-restangular 1.0.11 & @ngx-translate 7.0.0 in the same project. However, I can only ever get one of them to work at a time. I put log statements in each Factory that's called during import and only one of them ever gets called at a time.  I'm baffled!  Is there anyone who has successfully used both in Angular 4?

Here is a plunker that tries to include them both. https://plnkr.co/edit/ecefQcRHV3q5UTZa5H8q?p=preview.  Each one can work if the other is not included, but by putting them both in the app, only one works. (I haven't figured out a consistent way to make it switch to the other one -- just commenting out the one that's working doesn't always make the other one start working)

Here's my `app.ts` file (the module file):

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule, BaseRequestOptions, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { RestangularModule } from 'ngx-restangular';
import { MissingTranslationHandler, TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

import { App } from './app.component.ts';
import { routes } from './app.routes.ts';
import { MyMissingTranslationHandler } from './my-missing-translation-handler';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
  console.log("in translator config");
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

export function RestangularConfigFactory (RestangularProvider) {
  console.log("in restangular config");
  RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
    id: "_id"
  });
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [App],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    RestangularModule.forRoot(RestangularConfigFactory),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      missingTranslationHandler: {
        provide: MissingTranslationHandler,
        useClass: MyMissingTranslationHandler
      },
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [Http]
      }
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [App]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem must've had something to do with caching or building somehow. I ended up leaving both restangular and translate code in my project and eventually they both started working. It wasn't as simple as restarting `ng serve` (I'm using angular-cli) or refreshing my browser though. I'm not sure what finally triggered whatever fixed it, but the answer to the question is yes, they can both work in the same project!